# Store ajax data to php

Tags: php, ajax

I have a function.I want Data passing through ajax is store in php variable.I tried below code but not work please some one help me.

```
function moreinfo(prodid,catid,price,type,catname) {
url2="<?php echo $this-  >getUrl('compatibility/compatiblelist/moredetails'); ?>";
$j.ajax({
        url:url2,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"prodid": prodid},
        success: function(response) {alert(console.log(response));}
        });

<?php
 $ms = $_POST["prodid"];
 echo $ms;
 ?>

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`<?php ?>` tags only work when file name must be **.php**.
may you are using that process in .js file kindly change the ext

Comment: i am using .php file

Answer (score 0):

consider separating the file, .js and .php then you can include .js file

Answer (score 0):

```
function moreinfo(prodid,catid,price,type,catname) {
url2="something.php";
$.ajax({
        url:url2,
        async:false,
        type:'POST',
        data: {prodid: prodid},
        dataType:'html',
        success: function(response) {alert(console.log(response));}
        });
 }
```

In your something.php

```
<?php
 $ms = $_POST["prodid"];
 echo $ms;
 ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your anser,can we add this code in same file.if yes then how

Comment: regular practice is writing your php code in separate file. can't you try that way?